# Salesforce Email relay configurating using Sendgrid

Tags: smtp, salesforce, sendgrid

Currently we are using Sendgrid Email API. We are getting sendgrid message id in the response and we are using the same to update delivery event information.
If we send emails via SMTP relay (using Sendgrid SMTP relay), how can we get the sendgrid message id back to Salesforce?
Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: If you are getting the email ID back when sending with the REST API, why do you need to send with SMTP? Can you share how you are getting the message ID? As the response to sending a mail with the REST API has no body.

Comment: Thank you for reading and response. ID is in header not in the body. We want to use OOTB features, so using relay will avoid customisation.

Comment: I think you need to share some more details about what you’re doing. What out of the box feature are you using? How are you actually sending emails right now? Where is this taking place?